# Can I have LaTeX-style floats in Word?

Tags: latex, microsoft-word

I'm a (rather experimented) LaTeX-user... but unfortunately, I have to use Word (2000 (!)) at work. One of the things I miss the most (I mean, except the typographic quality, the macros and the math stuff :P) is the LaTeX-style float. Is there some way to put a picture in a floating position (eg, like with \begin{figure}[htp]) in Word?

Thanks,

Antony

Comment: right click on the figure, go to properties, and check the tabs. I am using a mac and I don't remember what the tabs are, but there will be one of them which will give you options of how to have your figure, and one (or most of them) will be float style if I am not mistaken.

Answer (score -2):

You can, I think it's described as the "text wrapping style".  See here:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/209944

EDIT: Actually, checking on my own copy of Word2k, it seems that there is nothing corresponding exactly to a LaTeX "float", even though it can do what Word calls floating.  LaTeX, as I understand it, can intelligently locate best place on the page to put an image.  The options you get with Word aren't intelligent like that, although you have a lot of options for placing an image and having text wrap around it.   Right click on the picture and choose "Format Picture", then go to the layout tab.  Or read more about "format picture" in help.

So whether Word can do "LaTeX-style floats" would depend on what you mean by LaTeX style floats.  I think you can get something close enough, though not quite the real thing, since there's no "intelligent" placement.

Comment: It seems to me that Word floats have nothing to do with LaTeX floats... What a pity.